# Java HashMap Sepator and Fields Data File

Tags: java, hashmap

I write to program to read data file field firstname, check in data file is there any dupicate firstname if there is duplicate firstname in data file, put number at end of line like sequction number like 0,1,2....

```
Data file in: 
CustmerNumber,FirstName,LastName,Address1,city
123456789,abcd,efgh,12 spring st,atlanta
2345678,xyz,lastname,16 sprint st,atlanta
232345678,abcd,efgh ,1201 sprint st,atlanta 
1234678,xyz,lastname,1234 oakbrook pkwy,atlanta
23556,abcd,efgh,3201 sprint st,atlanta
34564,robert,parker,12032 oakbrrok,atlanta

Out File Data File like: 

CustmerNumber,FirstName,LastName,Address1,city,**SEQNUMBER**
123456789,**abcd,efgh**,12 spring st,atlanta,**0**
232345678,**abcd,efgh** ,1201 sprint st,atlanta,**1** 
23556,**abcd,efgh**,3201 sprint st,atlanta,**2**
2345678,**xyz,lastname**,16 sprint st,atlanta,**0**
1234678,**xyz,lastname**,1234 oakbrook pkwy,atlanta,**1**
34564,**robert,parker**,12032 oakbrrok,atlanta,**0**
```

My Program is working fine:
I just have one question,

Here is my program,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<String, Integer> names = new HashMap<>();

        File dir = new File("Data_File_In");

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);

            s.nextLine();   

            while(s.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = s.nextLine();

                String[] actionID = line.split("\\,");

              //  String PFN = actionID[0].trim();
               // String PLN = actionID[1].trim();

                if(!names.containsKey(actionID[0].trim())) {
                    names.put(actionID[0].trim(), 0);
                }
                names.put(actionID[0].trim(), names.get(actionID[0].trim())+1);
            }
            for(String name : names.keySet()) {
                for(int i = 1; i <= names.get(name); i++) {
                    System.out.println(name + "---->" + (i-1));
                }
            }

            s.close();

        }

    }

}

System.out.println(name + "---->" + (i-1));

In This line its printing Name, that's only field right?? instead of that I want to print LINE..
```

And in output firstline its printing:-

```
---->0
need to remove this line as well
```

Is there anyway that I can print line instead of firstname field

Please help me, Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there anyway you can print line instead of firstname field? Sure: call System.out.println() without any arguments. If that's not your question, you might want to try being more specific.

Comment: my question is, System.out.println(name + "---->" + (i-1)); This line is printing name, field firstname, instead of that print LINE.. everline has 0,1,2....if there is duplicate in firstname is not than, only 0 at line of line..

Comment: You're printing a name, an arrow, and an integer. I'm not sure what you expect it to be printing? Are you trying to use that as an index to something?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the original input line somewhere. Also, you need to fix the indexing. First name is at index `1`, not index `0` in your array. Finally, you do not need a `\` before the comma in your regex.

I would recommend changing your map to store a list of all the lines for a first name in the value. The length of the list will provide you with the count you want. If you want the output to be sorted, you should also use a `SortedMap` such as `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<String, List<String>> names = new HashMap<>();

        File dir = new File("Data_File_In");

        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(file);

            s.nextLine();   

            while(s.hasNextLine()) {

                String line = s.nextLine();

                String[] actionID = line.split(",");

              //  String PFN = actionID[0].trim();
               // String PLN = actionID[1].trim();

                String name = actionID[1].trim();

                if(!names.containsKey(name)) {
                    names.put(name, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                names.get(name).add(line);
            }
            for(List<String> lines : names.values()) {
                for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(lines.get(i) + "," + i);
                }
            }

            s.close();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, its giving me error:-,0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at test1.main(test1.java:46)
Please help me thanks

Comment: @user3187463. Fixed. I had `i <= lines.size()` instead of `i < lines.size()` towards the end. My mistake